# Rails uglifier breaks js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, uglifier

I am using asset pipeline with uglifier. Turns out, that `uglifier` breaks on of js library. I am trying to trace it down, but got stuck.

So in `production.rb` I have `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` but it seems is not using uglifier gem from `bundle show uglifier` - I put there some debug statements and they don't show.
I will dive into rails code now, but if someone knows, how rails js_compressor lookup works, would be helpful. I am using Rails 5.2

Answer (score 2):

Try `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)`

Comment: I was having a similar issue, in my production environment, the generated application-hash.js was in a different order than it should be, and some of my js libs were broken. This line solved it, thank you!